# Meaning of the verb "channel" in the following context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> This cue can be used to evince discomfort about  particular issues and helps **channel** the investigative inquiry.

Does it mean the helps to lead the inquiry in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

According to [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/channel), in this context applies definition #3:

> **channel**:
>
> 3. To direct or guide along some desired course: channels her curiosity into research; channel young people into good jobs.